# Local Storage in JavaScript - how to make sure all data is stored in local storage?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, local-storage

What is preventing my data from being stored in local storage? A way to check is to close the browser and open it again to see if the data is stored, but so far it is not retaining the information despite similar sample code working.

```js
//all task information saved in local storage 
//check to see whether local storage supported and available
function storageAvailable(type) {
    var storage;
    try {
        storage = window[type];
        var x = '__storage_test__';
        storage.setItem(x, x);
        storage.removeItem(x);
        return true;
    }
    catch(e) {
        return e instanceof DOMException && (
            // everything except Firefox
            e.code === 22 ||
            // Firefox
            e.code === 1014 ||
            // test name field too, because code might not be present
            // everything except Firefox
            e.name === 'QuotaExceededError' ||
            // Firefox
            e.name === 'NS_ERROR_DOM_QUOTA_REACHED') &&
            // acknowledge QuotaExceededError only if there's something already stored
            (storage && storage.length !== 0);
    }
}

//check to see if local storage usable
if (storageAvailable('localStorage')) {
     console.log('Yes! We can use localStorage')
  }
  else {
     console.log('No, no localStorage')
  }

  //check to see if local storage populated
  if(!localStorage.getItem('sort', 'newTask', 'taskDescr', 'startDate', 'category', 'priority')) {
    populateStorage();
    console.log('Storage populated')
  } else {
    empty();
    console.log('Storage not populated')
  }

  //create two data entries in local storage, and then delete them
  function populateStorage() {
    localStorage.setItem('sort', 'A');
    localStorage.setItem('newTask', 'coffee');
    console.log('Data entries in local storage populated')
  
    //localStorage.clear();
    //console.log('Local storage cleared')
  }

  // Check browser support
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
  // Store
  localStorage.setItem("sort", "A");
  // Retrieve
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("sort");
  console.log("result")
} else {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support Web Storage...";
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but `getItem()` takes **a single** key, you are passing it several. Related: you do call `empty()` if some data is present.

Comment: I see, thank you for pointing that out! I will correct it. Should I be repeating the if, else code for each key I want to fall under getItem()?

Comment: I don't really understand what this code is used for. Generally you want to use the values that have been saved, so you'd assign these to some variables or store them in an other object. Here you are only looking if they're being set to a non-empty string, I can't really see how this can be useful, but it's your code, not mine.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your input. I'm just trying to  make sure all data from a to-do list I've created is stored in local storage, but it looks like I am missing important aspects of the code to do this

Comment: As above, single key:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem  `if (localStorage.getItem('sort') && localStorage.getItem('newTask') && localStorage.getItem('taskDescr'...)) { ...ok ... } else { populateStorage(); }`

Comment: Thank you so much!